# Can you join Section 31 by choice?

Tags: star-trek, section-31

In *Star Trek: Deep Space Nine*, Bashir is "recruited" by Sloan and in *Discovery*, Georgiou and Ash Tyler are recruited into Section 31.

In any canon material, has anyone ever joined Section 31 by choice? Do they choose who they want and attempt to recruit you?

Comment: How exactly do you expect people to apply to join a top-secret organization that they don't even know exists?

Comment: @Chronocidal - In Discovery S31 operated openly, a member of Discovery, who agreed with S31's goals and methods could ask to join. Bashir mentioned S31 to Sisko and O'Brian, Sisko if he agreed with S31 could have asked to join. According to the [Star Trek Database](https://ca.startrek.com/database_article/sloan), S31 is part of SF intelligence, many officers might be aware of S31 and wish to join.

Comment: It does seem he was "recruited", but Malcom Reed in Enterprise was at least _willing_ and excited about the work at the time he was recruited - [see script](http://www.chakoteya.net/Enterprise/92.htm) .